# How to reference a document when a PUT request is made

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I am building an app of Todo Lists, and each list will have an x amount of tasks. The problem is I thought i could do something like this in the taskschema to reference the list the task belongs to:

```
list: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'list'
}
```

Here´s the full code of my models:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const listSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        unique: false,
        required: [true, 'debes escribir un titulo']
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    }
})


const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const taskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        unique: false,
        required: true
    },
    doned: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    updatedAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
    // a task belongs to a list:
    list: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'list'
    }
})
```

But it seems there´s no much help in the web in how to make that work using that approach.

So I took a look at mongoDb documentation and they say they recommend using [manual references](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/)

So i changed like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const taskSchema = require('./task')

const listSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        unique: false,
        required: [true, 'debes escribir un titulo']
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
    tasks: [
        taskSchema
    ]
})
```

But now I´m clueless in how each time I create a task (a POST request to task is made) how I am at the same time will be related to a certain list.

Here´s my api routes for tasks:

```
routerTasks.post('/task', (req,res, next) => {

    Task.create(req.body)
        .then(task => res.send(task))
        .catch(next)

})
routerTasks.put('/task/:idTask', (req, res) => {

    Task.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.idTask, req.body)
        .then(task => res.send({nueva_informacion: task}))
        .catch()
})
```

and for my lists:

```
routerLists.post('/list', (req, res, next) => {

    List.create(req.body).then((list) => {
        res.send(list)
    }).catch(next)
})
routerLists.put('/list/:id', (req, res) => {

    List.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body)
        .then(list => res.send({nueva_informacion: list}))
})
```

My question is... **maybe I should create the tasks in a put request of the newly created list**? In that case, then the POST request of tasks are useless?

here´s the error that gives me when i try to add a Task and at the same time referencing it to a list:

```js
routerTasks.post('/task/:listId', (req,res, next) => {
    
    List.findOne({_id: req.params.listId}).then((record) => {
        record.tasks.push(req.body);
        record.save()
    })
})
// TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `model` is not a valid type within the array `tasks`
```